# How can the array variable be assigned from a method (shown in the program)?

Tags: java

How is it possible for circleArray to be equated to createCircleArray() ?

```
public class TotalArea {
 /** Main method */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Declare circleArray
    CircleWithPrivateDataFields[] circleArray;

    // Create circleArray
    circleArray = createCircleArray();

 // Print circleArray and total areas of the circles
   printCircleArray(circleArray);
 }

 /** Create an array of Circle objects */
 public static CircleWithPrivateDataFields[] createCircleArray() {
```

Comment: It's not "equated". It's **assigned**. The result of invoking the method (the value that is *returned* from the method) is *assigned* to the array variable.

Answer (score 0):

Because the method `createCircleArray()` returning an array of same type that `circleArray` have. Hence it is assignable.

Instead of assigning it directly, it is possible that to have a method and return from that method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what the question was but: 
It all depends on what createCircleArray() returns.
If you write 
    int myint = myIntCreater();
then myInt will be resolved to the return value of myIntCreater(), and hopefully myIntCreater() returns an int or else there will be exceptions thrown

Answer (score 0):

The variable circleArray is not being equated with a method; instead, it is being defined as the **return value** of that method. In this case, the createCircleArray method returns an array, meaning that you can set its value (an array, in this case) equal to any array variable.